# Use : colon character in weird argument — expl3

Tags: expl3, latex3, catcodes

Since `\ExplSyntaxOn` changes catcode of `:` it makes command with weird argument break when using the macro outside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \my_foo:w #1:#2\q_stop {
  (#1)
}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
  \my_foo:w #1:\q_stop
}

\foo{abc:def} % works
\ExplSyntaxOff

\foo{abc:def} % doesn't work

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there constant like `\c_math_subscript_token` but for colon?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that in the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` the colon has category code 11, but in the document it has category code 12.

You can store the desired parameter text in a token list and then use its value:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 \c_colon_str ##2 }
\exp_last_unbraced:NNV \cs_set:Npn \my_foo:w \l_tmpa_tl \q_stop
 {
  (#1)
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  \my_foo:w #1:\q_stop
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{abc:def}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm trying to skip an intermediate `\l_tmpa_tl` variable, but why doesn't `\exp_last_unbraced:NNx \cs_set:Npn \my_foo:w { ##1 \c_colon_str ##2 } \q_stop { (#1) }` work?

Comment: @antshar Because there is no `\exp_last_unbraced:NNx` function?

Comment: Oh right.. I forgot that it doesn't have all the possibilities of arguments. That's unfortunate.

Comment: Just figured out a workaround: `\exp_args:NNNx \exp_last_unbraced:NNo \cs_set:Npn \my_foo:w { ##1 \c_colon_str ##2 } \q_stop { (#1) }`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of changing the colon in the definition you could also change the catcode before reading the argument, that has the advantage that your command will work inside and outside \ExplSyntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \__antshar_foo:w #1:#2\q_stop {
  (#1)
}

\cs_new:Npn \foo 
 {
  \group_begin: \char_set_catcode_letter:N :
  \__anthshar_foo_aux:n  
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__anthshar_foo_aux:n  #1
 {
  \group_end: \__antshar_foo:w #1:\q_stop
 } 


\foo{abc:def} % works

\ExplSyntaxOff

\foo{abc:def} % works

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a workaround (but the definition is global).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

{
\catcode`\: = 12
\expandafter \gdef \csname my_foo:w \endcsname #1 : #2 \q_stop  { (#1) }
}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{ \my_foo:w #1:\q_stop }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\foo{abc:def} % does work

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to produce a string version of the colon. There are a few ways: one example:

```latex
\use:x
  {
    \cs_set:Npn \exp_not:N \my_foo:w
      ##1 \token_to_str:N : ##2 \exp_not:N \q_stop
  }
  { ( #1 ) }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use TeX primitive `\def`, no Expl3:

```
\def\foo#1{\fooA#1\end}
\def\fooA#1:#2\end{(#1)}

\foo{abc:def} % works
```

Comment: Yeah with plain tex it's straight forward, I have been asking about latex3 syntax because there `:` is a special character so it has to be treated specifically.

Comment: latex3 syntax is only additional complication. A have shown that if we leave it then some things are more simple.